# With OpenGL 4.3, how do I correctly use glVertexAttribFormat/Binding?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

I was trying to use this feature, here is what I did:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo_id);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao_id);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo_id);
glBindVertexArray(m_vao_id);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // Color
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);  // Texture coordinates

glVertexAttribFormat(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexAttribBinding(0, m_vbo_id);
glVertexAttribFormat(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24* sizeof(float));
glVertexAttribBinding(1, m_vbo_id);
glVertexAttribFormat(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 42* sizeof(float));
glVertexAttribBinding(2, m_vbo_id);

glBindVertexBuffer(m_vbo_id, m_buffer_data[00], 54*sizeof(float), 0);
glBindVertexBuffer(m_vbo_id, m_buffer_data[18], 54*sizeof(float), 0);
glBindVertexBuffer(m_vbo_id, m_buffer_data[42], 54*sizeof(float), 0);
```

`m_bufferdata` is a `std::array<float, 54>`, containing all the floats, which is rebuilt every frame.
This will generate a GL_INVALID_OPERATION. Can anyone tell me why or how I correctly order the calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of [`glVertexAttribBinding`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribBinding.xhtml) is not the buffer object, but the binding index.
The arguments of [`glBindVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) are the binding index, the buffer object, the offset and the stride. Stride is `(3+4+2)*sizeof(float)` for a tightly packed buffer:

```cpp
int bindingindex = 0;

glVertexAttribFormat(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexAttribBinding(0, bindingindex);
glVertexAttribFormat(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24* sizeof(float));
glVertexAttribBinding(1, bindingindex);
glVertexAttribFormat(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 42* sizeof(float));
glVertexAttribBinding(2, bindingindex);

glBindVertexBuffer(bindingindex, m_vbo_id, 0, 9*sizeof(float));
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. Second, could you explain what binding index is or represents?

Comment: @TuxStash.de See [Separate attribute format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format)